# Tips on solving fast search algorithm assignment 

Tags: c, file-io, binary

I have a huge text file (50 MB) with key/values that looks something like this:

```
...
ham 2348239
hehe 1233493
hello 1234213
hello 1812394
hello 1923943
help 2038484
helping 2342394
hesitate 1298389
...
```

Basically it is a lot of words, with the value being a pointer to the position of that word in another file, which contains an entire fiction novel.

The assignment is to write a very fast search algorithm, by creating an hash table index of all letter combinations AAA-ZZZ and storing it in a file. The hashed value should point to the first occurrence of the word starting with that three letters, eg. combination `HEH` should point to `hehe`, and `HEL` should point to the first `hello` etc..

So If I search for `help`, `HEL` will get hashed and I will receive a pointer to the first `hello`, and by looking up the next index in my hash table, I will get a pointer to `hesitate`, thus having access to the entire range of words starting with `HEL`.

To find the word `help` in the range, the assignment suggests to do a binary search.

I actually managed to solve this, but the solution was quite ugly, much due to the text file described above.

I was thinking there must be a more elegant way to structure the key/value text file.. Perhaps binary.

Any advice appreciated!

**EDIT**

Sorry for unspecified question. I just wanted some input from the community... perhaps some best practice advice on how to solve this problem.

Here's the code building my hashTable:

```
while ((fscanf(indexFile, "%s %lu\n%n", buf, &bookPos, &rowLength)) != EOF){
    newHash = calcHashIndex(buf);
    if (curHash < newHash){
        curHash++;
        indexPos = ftell(indexFile) - rowLength;
        for (;curHash <= newHash; curHash++){
            hashTable[curHash] = indexPos;
        }
        curHash = newHash;
    }
}
fwrite(hashTable, sizeof(hashTable), 1, hashTableFile);
```

And here's the code for doing the binary search in the indexFile. Actually it doesn't really work... Some random words with just 1 occurrence does not return as a match.

```
int binarySearch(unsigned char *searchWord, FILE * file, long firstIndex, long lastIndex){
    unsigned char buf[WORD_LEN];
    long bookPos, middle;
    int cmpVal, rowLength;

    while (firstIndex < lastIndex){
        middle = (firstIndex + lastIndex)/2;
        fseek(file, middle, SEEK_SET);
        goBackToLastNewLine(file, 0);
        fscanf(file, "%s %lu\n%n", buf, &bookPos, &rowLength);
        if (strcmp(searchWord, buf) <= 0){
            lastIndex = ftell(file) - rowLength;
        } else {
            firstIndex = ftell(file);
        }
    }

    fseek(file, -rowLength, SEEK_CUR);
    return (strcmp(searchWord, buf) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far (show us some code) and where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you mean converting the information to binary? If so that will not actually change much since ascii is already an optimal binary representation of character data. If you mean resorting the file into a binary tree, I think this would actually make your binary search between indexes more complicated since you now have a tree to traverse within a tree.

Answer (score 1):

its difficult because an ideal algoithm looking for hello should return all three hello's

```
void binary_search(int index1, int index2, char* value, int* range){
    int range_size = (index2 - index1);

    if( range_size == 0 ){
         range[0] = range[1] = -1;
         return;
    }

    int middle_index = (range_size / 2) + index1;
    char* current_line = get_file_line(middle_index);

    int str_compare = strcmp(current_line,value);

    if(str_compare > 0 ) { 
        binary_search(index1, middle_index-1, value, range);
    } else if (str_compare < 0 ) { 
        binary_search(middle_index+1, index2, value, range);
    } else {
        find_whole_range(middle_index, value);
    }
} 

void find_whole_range(int index, char* value, int* range){

    range[0] = index;
    range[1] = index; 


    while( strcmp( get_file_line( range_top - 1 ), value) == 0 )
        range[0]--;

    while( strcmp( get_file_line( range_top + 1 ), value) == 0 )
        range[1]++;
}
```

EDIT: this is untested, im sure some of the referenceing/derefernce is wrong and you might want to double check that i dont have the values from strcmp flipped...

Answer (score 0):

an idea for a solution to your very unspecific question: use a database (mySQL f.e.). That has everything you need with the engeneered knowledge of over 40 years of DBMS desinging and building.

Comment: That is not much help for a homework assignment that expects you to implement the algorithms yourself.

Comment: sure you are right, but this answer may give some "extra points" for knowing the appropriate tools at the right time. if (f.e.) a want-to-be-a-new-employee in an interview for application development starts to show code to do the thing, i would not think good of him. If he says DBMS would be a good tool, i would give him a chance.